# PDF Forms: How can I get the Computer Modern font to work with PDF widgets?

Tags: fonts, pdf, forms

I'm an industrial engineer and I want to create a check list for my team in order to simplify job tasks.  My idea is to realize said checklist through fillable PDF forms with javascript support in order to do some magic calculations.

I am using LaTeX with `eforms` package (part of `acroTeX` bundle) now to achieve this, but I have a serious problem especially with computer modern font in term of the use with PDF widgets like textfield and pushbutton label.

According to the font tab of my Adobe Reader the `cmr10` is embedded in my file, but why is Helvetica always chosen by this viewer?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Are PDF widgets the same as PDF forms? If so, I would suggest to use PDF forms in the headline.